# Flex 4 - manifest breaking spark

Tags: apache-flex, air, manifest, flashdevelop, flex4.10

When I use the following namespace command line argument (in FlashDevelop's additional compiler options) and declaration, spark components (SolidColor, GradientEntry, etc.) are no longer resolved to component implementations:

```
-namespace library://ns.shinynet.com/flex/shinylib lib/manifest.xml
xmlns:sn="library://ns.shinynet.com/flex/shinylib"
```

Everything works fine when I explicitly declare them with

```
xmlns:sn="com.shinynet.shinylib.components.*"
```

But, of course, I'd much rather use a manifest to make updating and organization easier. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I've had similar issues with some spark components (`View`/`ViewNavigator`,`Callout`) when I use namespaces and have to specifically declare `xmlns:sComponents="spark.components.*"`. Interestingly it only started to happen when I moved over to Apache Flex.

Comment: Eh, I hope it's not an Apache Flex wide issue. But, I suppose anything is still better than Flex being abandoned.